# Find common shortest edge between multiple paths in tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

Given a undirected, weighted tree (N node, N-1 bidirectional edge, not necessarily binary tree).
Input will be simple paths (from  start node to lowest common ancestor to finish node) between some nodes, for example 1->4, 2->10. Find the shortest edge common (belonging) to all given paths.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, have a count at each node for number of paths crossing it. After setting up these counts, process the tree and find the shortest common edge. A common edge would be one where the counts of each end-point would be equal to the number of paths.

```
i = 0

// set up counts
for each path p
  for each node n on path
    if n.count != i // early path stop condition, past common ancestor
      break // go to next path
    n.count++
  i++

current = root
shortestEdge = null

// find shortest edge
while true
  for each child c of current
    if c.count == pathCount
      shortestEdge = shortest(shortestEdge, edge(current, c))
      current = c
      break // out of for-loop
    else
      stop // stop while-loop
```